# How to view the headers that were sent, using node-fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I'm trying to figure out how to access the headers that were sent by a node-fetch request. When i do this, for example:

```
const response = await fetch('http://playground.localhost')
```

The response object seems to contain only information about the response(like **response headers**, body, url, etc), without any "Request" object, like Axios exposes. In the latter you would be able to access the headers via response.request.headers.

Is there any way to show information about the actual request, and not just the response?

Answer (score -3):

This might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#accessing-headers-and-other-meta-data

````
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.ok);
        console.log(res.status);
        console.log(res.statusText);
        console.log(res.headers.raw());
        console.log(res.headers.get('content-type'));
    });```
````

Comment: Nah, this refers to the response headers. I need the request headers :D

Comment: Sorry @i.brod, I just re-read your question more carefully. Hope somebody else can help.

Comment: Well what i ended up doing is just copying the default headers that fetch sends...but this is of course not "bullet proof"

Comment: Thank @Andy. I was looking for a way to get response header and your answer helped me out